# Photoshop - How to delete all hidden layer from selected Artboard only?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Currently when I choose to "Delete Hidden Layers", it deletes all hidden layer from all the artboards. How to delete hidden layers from some specific artboard only.

Obviously, in a basic setup it doesn't make much difference, but when you're working on 40-50 artboards setup with over 5-8 thousand of images then it really matters

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail why you want to delete these hidden layers from just one artboard?

Comment: @SSDesigns  OK, Suppose I'm working on a mobile app with 20 screens, to reduce recursive design I 'intentionally' hide some layer on some particular screens like a pop-up window on the home screen or navigation drawers on some other screen. But in the design process when I want to delete all unused layer from any artboard in one click it deletes all from all the artboards.

Comment: Ah I understand. Unfortunately, I don't think that there is a way to just selectively delete the hidden layers from just a single artboard.

Comment: It's a command that applies to all artboards, even locking your hidden layers will not protect them from being deleted. I'm quite certain this isn't possible at all.

Comment: @SSDesigns Yes, there is a way, I found it, please check the answer

Comment: Just so you know.... you cannot apply a bounty to your own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering to my own question after 4 Days, maybe it helps to someone else.

[image]

Deleting all hidden layers from a selected Artboard is simple once you follow these steps:

1. Select the Artboard where you want to delete all of the hidden layers

   You can select more than one at a time
2. Change Layer Filter to > Artboard

   **Layer** Filter is located in Layers Panel, it is the first Element
3. Select > Delete Hidden Layers

   Delete Hidden Layers option is located in Layers Panel's Menu
4. Now Change Layer Filter to > Kind

Done! All hidden layers are deleted from selected Artboard(s) only.

Comment: I don’t know why you keep rolling back the edits but please stop using blockquotes and code formatting for things other than quotes or code